# Why does this goofy positioning cause changes on this site?

Tags: css

If you go to this site: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/social-networking-for-social-smokers-2011-05-11 and go into the styles and change `<div id="blanket"></div>` to having a position of static, and then add a wrapper outside of it (or on the body) put `position:relative` on it, the page changes drastically (the header basically overlaps the content area at that point.

Everything I know about positioning tells me this shouldn't be happening, but I can't quite figure out why. I wasn't able to find anything in the CSS to cause this behavior as well. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: This isn't related to my job or anything but my friend brought it to my attention and I thought it was a brain tickler.

I've tried doing this:

```
<body>
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: static;">
        <div id="blanket">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And this doesn't cause the problem, so there is clearly something on that page, but I can't figure it out. It does this in chrome/FF/IE.

Comment: It could have something to do with the 212 Errors, 175 warning(s) that the w3c found wrong with the Markup of this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inspecting the elements in the header. You will see the following style rules on the `div#topchrome` element:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 981px;
z-index: 10000;
```

The `position` on this element (`absolute`, with `top: 0`) causes it to be pushed to the very top of the page (default, unmodified behavior). If you change `body` to have `position: relative;`, you have basically told `#topchrome` to be "absolute, but relative to where `body` is." So now, `#topchrome` is actually at the top of body, which is the very top of the page. Even so, that still shouldn't change things. The real culript is the third actor, `div#breakingnews`, which has the property `margin-top: 177px`. In the new flow, we have:

```
body { position: relative; }
     div#breakingnews { margin-top: 177px; }
     div#chrome
          div#topchrome { position: absolute; top: 0; }
```

So, `div#breakingnews` is causing the content to be pushed down. Indeed, changing `div#blanket` to have `position: static` has nothing to do with it, since it is `static` (the default) to begin with.

Comment: I am not sure if this is right as topchrome is staying positioned underneath breakingnews, which it doesn't if body isn't relatively positioned. I think the problem is that topchrome is not, in fact, getting put right underneath the body tag, as you state
but it is getting bumped down underneath that margin, which it shouldn't be, and doesn't if body is not relatively positioned.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your explanation, but would there be a solution to prevent that from happening while still keeping body's position to relative?